# change styling of last line thru jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the code below to change the styling of the last text line within a h3 tag. What I want is that the last line of every h3 tag colors red. Now only the last line of the last h3 tag colors red. Can anyone help please?

```js
$("h3").contents().last().wrap('<span id="lastLineTourTitle"></span>');
```

```css
#lastLineTourTitle {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="product">
    <h3>
    This is a test<br>and this is the last line  (1).
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h3>
    This is a test<br>and this is the last line (2).
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
  <h3>
    This is a test<br>and this is the last line  (3).
  </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you always have 2 lines, then you might use `:first-line` to style the first line. Unfortunately there is no `:last-line` equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to loop over all the `h3` elements and wrap the content individually.

Also note that you're creating elements with duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid. Change the `span` to use a `class` instead, like this:

```js
$("h3").each(function() {
    $(this).contents().last().wrap('<span class="lastLineTourTitle"></span>');
});
```

```css
.lastLineTourTitle {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="product">
    <h3>Dit is een test<br>en dit is de tweede regel (1).</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h3>Dit is een test<br>en dit is de tweede regel (2).</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h3>Dit is een test<br>en dit is de tweede regel (3).</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Eddy no problem, glad to help